# Rails 3 : Add some methods in models, for development

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, initialization, metaprogramming

I would like to add some methods to some AR Models of my App; but I think they should only be available *under some circumstances*; this requires some meta-programming.

So I'd like to have a file where I put all my debug methods, the only question is **where** to put it?

Example, I have the models:

```
class Admin::Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base 
class Admin::Order < ActiveRecord::Base
```

And in my file I have (it does deppend on `MetaWhere.operator_overload!` initialization):

```
if Rails.env != 'production'

  class Admin::Order

    def self.mock_make
      r = Restaurant.first
      user_query = User.where( :created_at > "2011-04-01"  )
      u = user_query.first( :offset => ( user_query.count * rand ).to_i )

      o = r.orders.new
      o.user = u
      o.value = rand(100) + rand.round(2)

      if o.save
        return o
      else
        return nil
      end
    end

  end

end
```

The thing is.. I can't get it to work on `/config/initializers` or `/app/models`.

Comment: Why don't you use something already made for this purpose such as FactoryGirl: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl ?  The code appears to be brittle.

Comment: @Patrick It may be brittle, anyhow, I need to span some orders irt in order to dev, do I need a dependency for that? No

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap it as a external module and include it with `if` condition

```
class MyClass << ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyExtraModule if Rails.env == 'development'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Put them in `config/environments/development.rb`